# Power Pivot Divide by 0 Percent Calculation Error in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dax, powerpivot

Good day to everyone, I am having a problem where I am creating a measure in Power Pivot Excel where the goal is to create a Accuracy Percentage based upon the division of 2 columns. Please see the attached picture below.

[image: Pivot Table]

As you can see, dividing by 0 gives a 100 percent accuracy when it reality it should be blank and or not counted. The formula i am using for this percentage calculation is listed below.

```
=
IF (
    ISBLANK (
        1 - DIVIDE (
                ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( '03a Qry for Inaccurate Count'[KEY] ) ),
                ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( Std_MainData[KEY] ) )
            )
    ),
    0,
    1 - DIVIDE (
            ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( '03a Qry for Inaccurate Count'[KEY] ) ),
            ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( Std_MainData[KEY] ) )
        )
)
```

Please let me know if this is possible to fix, thanks.

Comment: why not just use `=iferror((A2-B2)/A2,"")` ?

Comment: hi, i tried what you suggested and it still didnt work, the calculation is still showing 100% ---- FORMULA USED ----  =IFERROR((1-DIVIDE((DISTINCTCOUNT('03a Qry for Inaccurate Count'[KEY])),(DISTINCTCOUNT(Std_MainData[KEY])))),"")

Comment: without the original data.. it is impossible for others to replicate / test your formula. | May I know the exact cell location of the above screenshot-ed table? & in which cell the formula was applied?